# Ember.js - How to deal with API-Platform - resource link instead of Id in payload

Tags: ember.js, api-platform.com

I use Emberjs 3.2 with Api-Platform and I ran into the following problem:

Here is my API payload:

```
{
      "id": "/api/articles/0d8cb40c-221b-4c54-9e29-43877093b839",
      "type": "Article",
      "attributes": {
        "_id": "0d8cb40c-221b-4c54-9e29-43877093b839",
        "title": "Article",
        "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>",
        "dateCreated": "2018-07-17T18:20:29+03:00",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-07-17T18:20:29+03:00"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "author": {
          "data": {
            "type": "User",
            "id": "/api/users/b26e0381-6800-4f47-b269-9a92b27ad331"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I got an IRI instead of id in the payload.

I turned on api-platform option: allow_plain_identifiers: true
but I still get IRI instead of ID for the related entities.

How can I deal with this using EmberData JSONApi Adapter?

I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: I don't know how to configure API Platform (never dealt with it) but if it's impossible to fix on that side, you can play around with serializers on ember side. For example, `normalizeResponse` method of serializer can be used. Or `handleResponse` method of adapter.

Comment: transform it to a link relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember data provides a helpful serializer method to deal with this exact case: `normalizeResponse`.

You can create a serializer using `ember generate serializer <modelName>` (if this pattern is needed for all of the models, you can create an `application` serializer or inherit from base serializer. Likely you need this for either one or all of your models.

The Ember guides provide the exact solution to this: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/

In your example, you could do something like this:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload.data.id = payload.data.attributes._id;
    delete payload.data.attributes._id;

    return this._super(...arguments);
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem using JSONAPISerializer.